# passing a php array item into a javascript popup window to be edited and updated in mysql db

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, insert

I am creating a diabetes management system for a university project. One of the features of this system is for the patient to be able to send latest glucose readings and for the nurse to be able to login and comment on those readings.

I have been able to code the patient feature, however I wish to add a comment button in the comments column, which when clicked, brings up a popup window or a textbox for the nurse to be able to comment on that specific record. If a comment has not already been entered, an empty box should come up, however if there has been a previously entered comment, it should be displayed in the box to be updated and sent back to the mysql database. I would like to ask if someone could give me a way to include this comment box and code for the existing value to be displayed in the box and if there is no existing comment, then a new comment can be entered and stored in the database.

Below is my php code.

```php
 <?php//run query
    $result = mysql_query($GetReadings);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Glucose Level</th>
    <th>SBP</th>
    <th>DBP</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
</tr>

<?php
    //display results
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["Date"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Time"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["GlucoseLevel"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["SBP"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["DBP"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Comments"];
<?php
//if statement to add comment link if user is a nurse
if ($_SESSION['User_level'] == 2)
    {
     //code for comments
    }
 ?> </td>
</tr>

<?php
        //end of while loop
    }
?>
```

Hope I haven't missed out any crucial information.

Comment: alright, so what do you want us to help in?

Comment: Please mention your question in the post. According to your question title, you will have to write some javascript code. If you have already written then please provide that code.

Comment: I am sorry, i have no javascript code. I wrote it because i know it has to be done in javascript i think, but not sure how to go about it. Thanks

Comment: paaji, so do you have the code for the part which you've commented as 'code for comments' or is that where we've to help you?

Comment: That is where i would like help please. I am sorry i haven't been clear.

Comment: all right. last question. are you using jQuery or simply javascript, coz my answer will be based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript function :

```
window.open(URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])
```

Where, `URL - desired URL to display a page containing Textbox`, use any window name you want.

Echo `<a>` or `button` with a onclick event eg:

```
<a href="#" onlick="window.open('somePage.php?id=<? echo $row['id']?>', 'Window Name')">Add Comment</a>
```

**Edit**

The most basic way to achieve is, echo a `<div></div>` containing the past comments, the text box for new comments and Send/Cancel buttons. The trick is to set the `display:none` style property of that div. You the following code a guideline :
Echo the following code if the User has right user level.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showComment('<?php echo $row['id']?>')">Show Comments</a>

<div id="comment-<?php echo $row['id']?>" style="display:none">
    //display previous comments

    <form method="post" action="addComment.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">
        <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" /><input type="button" onclick="hideComment('<?php echo $row['id']?>')">
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideComment(id) {
        document.getElementById('comment-' + id).style.display = 'none';
    }

    function showComment(id) {
        document.getElementById('comment-' + id).style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I wanted to create a popup window rather than going to another page? and the popup window to have a comment box with the value of the '$row['Comments']' and once the ok or comment buton is click within the popup window, the new value should be updated on the database with an update query. Thank you

Comment: The function that I have mentioned opens a new window (popup). Please have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp. Write the code to display comments is the page (in `somePage.php`) you can do that by passing `ID` as a `GET` parameter to that page, using that display the comments.

Comment: The open() method opens a new browser window. I think i have worded it the wrong way. by popup window i mean something similar to an alert box with an ok buttton and a textbox with value of the comment? accept in this case it will be labeled 'send comment'

Comment: There is no ready made box like alert box which contains text box, OK/Cancel button, etc. You will have to write Javascript code for that to insert new elements into the existing page which looks like a box. Do you have basic knowledge of Javascript and how to use DOM ?

Comment: I do have basic knowledge of it yes, but have never practically done. If you could guide me in the right direction that will be much appreciated.

Comment: did you just say something like alert box? Are you looking for prompt() ?

Comment: yes i have just looked at the function. and i am looking for something similar to the showprompt function. I am not sure how to pass the value of '$row['Comments']' and when the ok button is clicked, how to pass that back to php so that i can update into mysql db.